# Getting a symbol lookup error message when running a perl script: "...vxs.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck"

Tags: linux, perl, perl-module

I'm trying to install a program name RAST which is written in perl and that's not going smoothly.
I'm following the installation procedure for Linux that can be found [here](https://blog.theseed.org/servers/installation/distribution-of-the-seed-server-packages.html) (as well as the installation file that can be downloaded there), and includes the following commands:

```
mkdir sas
cp ~/Downloads/sas.tgz sas
cd sas
TOP=`pwd`
tar -zxvf sas.tgz
cd modules
./BUILD_MODULES
export PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:$TOP/lib:$TOP/modules/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$TOP/bin
```

The error message is

```
perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/share/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/version/vxs/vxs.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
Build URI-1.53
perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/share/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/version/vxs/vxs.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
Build HTML-Tagset-3.03
perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/share/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/version/vxs/vxs.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
Build HTML-Parser-3.64
perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/share/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/version/vxs/vxs.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
Build libwww-perl-5.834
perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/share/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/version/vxs/vxs.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
Build Task-Weaken-1.02
perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/share/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/version/vxs/vxs.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

Linux PATH variable content:

```
/opt/software/miniconda3/bin
/opt/software/miniconda3/condabin
/opt/CREST
/usr/local/FastQC
/usr/local/IGV
/usr/local/IGVTools
/usr/local/MUMmer
/usr/local/TrimGalore-0.5.0
/usr/local/blast
/usr/local/bowtie2
/usr/local/circos/bin
/usr/local/fastx
/usr/local/bin/gatk
/usr/local/hisat2-2.1.0
/usr/local/mauve
/usr/local/mauve/linux-x64
/usr/local/mothur
/usr/local/mothur/blast/bin
/usr/local/ngsplot/bin
/usr/local/subread-1.6.3-Linux-x86_64/bin
/opt/jdk1.8.0_171/bin
/opt/jdk1.8.0_171/jre/bin
```

I saw 2 questions with a similar problem, but one doesn't provide a resolution, and the other includes removal of a module, which I can't do because I'm not the system's administrator. The system's perl version  is `perl 5, version 32, subversion 1 (v5.32.1) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi`. I tried using a conda environment with a perl-5.34.0, which gave the same error.

Comment: Can you share a minimal example of the script you used when the error occurred? See [mcve] for more information

Comment: You're using one build of Perl to load a module that was built using a different build of Perl. 1) You shouldn't be telling your Perl to access that directory in which this module is found. 2) You will need to install the module using the Perl that will be using it.

Comment: @HåkonHægland, I'm installing a program that's written in perl, rather than running a code I've written in perl, which I'll probably never do.

Comment: Thanks. @ikegami, 1) you mean I should remove that directory's path from PATH? and 2) I need to run the program with the same perl version in which the program is written.

Comment: @random *"I'm installing a program that's written in perl"* : Please include the commands you use to install the program, and what's the name of the program

Comment: @HåkonHægland, I added the commands and the program's name to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @random When I run the `BUILD_MODULES` script here (Ubuntu 22.04, perlbrew, perl version 5.34.1) it seems to work fine (no errors as I can see). Here is the log output: https://pastebin.com/90ssDtWT. Can you share the complete output log you get when you run `BUILD_MODULES` ? Then we can compare and try to locate the problem

Comment: Thanks @HåkonHægland. Do you think the problem I'm facing might be due to having multiple perl versions on PATH?

Comment: *"Do you think the problem I'm facing might be due to having multiple perl versions on PATH?"* That could be the problem yes. See the comment by @ikegami

Comment: Any ideas on how the solve the problem? I don't know how to apply @ikegami's suggestions.

Comment: If I'll post PATH's paths, will you be able to tell which paths might cause the conflict?

Comment: @random *"If I'll post PATH's paths, will you be able to tell which paths might cause the conflict?"* Yes please. And also if you can you share the complete output log you get when you run `BUILD_MODULES` ? Then we can compare and try to locate the problem that way

Comment: Great. I'll add to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252325/discussion-between-hakon-haegland-and-random).

Comment: Hey @HåkonHægland. Did you get my message on the chat page?

Comment: @random Sorry I did not get the message, let me check now

Comment: The chat doesn't notify me when you send a message, so it took me time to see your message, and maybe you don't get notified too so I write here as well. Kind of misses the whole point in communicating in the chat.

Comment: @random Yes that is not a good chat :) I have the same problem

Comment: Can we try google chat?

Comment: @HåkonHægland sure. We need to exchange email addresses?

Comment: @random Yes, you can find mine in my profile :)